# Efficient Function to Map (or Hash) Integers and Integer Ranges into Index

Tags: hash, dictionary, integer, range

We are looking for the computationally simplest function that will enable an indexed look-up of a function to be determined by a high frequency input stream of widely distributed integers and ranges of integers.

It is OK if the hash/map function selection itself varies based on the specific integer and range requirements, and the performance associated with the part of the code that selects this algorithm is not critical.   The number of integers/ranges of interest in most cases will be small (zero to a few thousand).  The performance critical portion is in processing the incoming stream and selecting the appropriate function.

As a simple example, please consider the following pseudo-code:

```
switch (highFrequencyIntegerStream)
    case(2)      : func1();
    case(3)      : func2();
    case(8)      : func3();
    case(33-122) : func4();

    ...

    case(10,000) : func40();
```

In a typical example, there would be only a few thousand of the "cases" shown above, which could include a full range of 32-bit integer values and ranges.   (In the pseudo code above 33-122  represents all integers from 33 to 122.)   There will be a large number of objects containing these "switch statements."

(Note that  the actual implementation will not include switch statements.  It will instead be a jump table (which is an array of function pointers) or maybe a combination of the Command and Observer patterns, etc.  The implementation details are tangential to the request, but provided to help with visualization.)

Many of the objects will contain "switch statements" with only a few entries.  The values of interest are subject to real time change, but performance associated with managing these changes is not critical.  Hash/map algorithms can be re-generated slowly with each update based on the specific integers and ranges of interest (for a given object at a given time).

We have searched around the internet, looking at  Bloom filters, various hash functions listed on  Wikipedia's "hash function" page and elsewhere, quite a few Stack Overflow questions, abstract algebra (mostly Galois theory which is attractive for its computationally simple operands), various ciphers, etc., but have not found a solution that appears to be targeted to this problem.  (We could not even find a hash or map function that considered these types of ranges as inputs, much less a highly efficient one.  Perhaps we are not looking in the right places or using the correct vernacular.)

The current plan is to create a custom algorithm that preprocesses the list of interesting integers  and ranges (for a given object at a given time) looking for shifts and masks that can be applied to input stream to help delineate the ranges.   Note that most of the incoming integers will be uninteresting, and it is of critical importance to make a very quick decision for as large a percentage of that portion of the stream as possible (which is why Bloom filters looked interesting at first (before we starting thinking that their implementation required more computational complexity than other solutions)).

Because the first decision is so important, we are also considering having multiple tables, the first of which would be inverse masks (masks to select uninteresting numbers) for the easy to find large ranges of data not included in a given "switch statement", to be followed by subsequent tables that would expand the smaller ranges.   We are thinking this will, for most cases of input streams, yield something quite a bit faster than a binary search on the bounds of the ranges.

Note that the input stream can be considered to be randomly distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty extensive theory of minimal perfect hash functions that I think will meet your requirement.  The idea of a minimal perfect hash is that a set of distinct inputs is mapped to a dense set of integers in 1-1 fashion.  In your case a set of N 32-bit integers and ranges would each be mapped to a unique integer in a range of size a small multiple of N.  Gnu has a perfect hash function generator called `gperf` that is meant for strings but might possibly work on your data.  I'd definitely give it a try. Just add a length byte so that integers are 5 byte strings and ranges are 9 bytes. There are some formal references on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).  A literature search in ACM and IEEE literature will certainly turn up more.

I just ran across [this library](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/) I had not seen before.

**Addition**

I see now that you are trying to map all integers in the ranges to the same function value.  As I said in the comment, this is not very compatible with hashing because hash functions deliberately try to "erase" the magnitude information in a bit's position so that values with similar magnitude are unlikely to map to the same hash value.

Consequently, I think that you will not do better than an optimal binary search tree, or equivalently a code generator that produces an optimal "tree" of "if else" statements.

If we wanted to construct a function of the type you are asking for, we could try using real numbers where individual domain values map to consecutive integers in the co-domain and ranges map to unit intervals in the co-domain.  So a simple floor operation will give you the jump table indices you're looking for.

In the example you provided you'd have the following mapping:

```
2 -> 0.0
3 -> 1.0
8 -> 2.0
33 -> 3.0
122 -> 3.99999
...
10000 -> 42.0 (for example)
```

The trick is to find a monotonically increasing polynomial that interpolates these points.  This is certainly possible, but with thousands of points I'm certain you'ed end up with something much slower to evaluate than the optimal search would be.

Comment: Tricking gperf into thinking our data is a string is an interesting idea.  We are also looking into CMPH as you suggested.  We have searched IEEE and ACM, but did not find anything that dealt with ranges.  A cursory glance into gperf and CMPH also seems to indicate that they do not handle ranges.   For example, if one were to use the bounds of the range in the gperf string, the hash function would not know to select something inside that range and map it to the correct index.  In our pseudo code above, for example, how would gperf know to map an input of 100 to the index associated with func4?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  Thought ranges were being extracted from the byte stream.  Now I see what you mean.  Let me think about it.

Comment: We spent some time last night working with gperf as suggested.  Note that if we were to use it for the second table in our proposed solution above, (after large ranges (and inverse ranges) were masked, and small ranges were expanded), we would have to include gperf and and a compiler as part of our release.  CMPH may be a better choice for this reason.  That being said, we are still hoping for a good way to include ranges as an integral part of the algorithm.

Comment: I should mention the classical way to do this is with a labeled balanced binary tree to represent interval limits.  Is that too slow? You can be sure no more than 1+log P nodes will need traversal where P is the number of target range values (treating single values as 1-element ranges).  So for you with ~2000 intervals this is perhaps 12 at about 5 instructions per level if carefully coded. So if the tree fits in L1 cache you are looking at maybe 100ns per lookup with an x86 kind of processor.

Comment: We did consider a binary search on the bounds (as intimated in the last paragraph of the original question) and understand that is pretty fast.  It feels like there must be a way to handle integer ranges in a hash-like alogorithm, using simple operands.  We also expect the masking approach to outperform the binary tree method.  As an aside, here is a [link](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx) to some simple hash functions that others searching this type of question might find helpful.

Comment: A search tree can be significantly better if you have probabilities associated with the search items.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Optimal_binary_search_trees Ranges and hashing don't mix well because hash functions _intentionally_ "erase" the magnitude information encoded in bits to    avoid values with similar magnitudes mapping to the same hash bucket. To effectively hash a range means intentionally causing adjacent values to "collide" in the same bucket, which is the exact opposite.  Not saying it can't be done, just why you are unlikely to find lots of references.

Comment: That is a great point.   It sounds like we may not know the correct vernacular to find such an algorithm.  By hash-like, we just meant that it will be a simple function that will map ranges to an index. (Incidentally, those keywords did not work for us either.)

Comment: I added more to the response.

Comment: We are still optimistic that we can do better than the binary search tree, but very much appreciate your analyses and other input.   We have accepted the answer, and are still very interested in any additional input you or others may like to provide.

Comment: Please let me know if you succeed.  I'd be interested.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps our [thoughts on hashing integers](http://programming.sirrida.de/programming.html#hash_integer) can help a little bit. You will also find there a hashing library (hashlib.zip) based on Bob Jenkins' work which deals with integer numbers in a smart way.
I would propose to deal with larger ranges after the single cases have been rejected by the hashing mechanism.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: You probably missed my statement "I would propose to deal with larger ranges after the single cases have been rejected by the hashing mechanism". This can indeed be a solution. On the other hand I consider simply repeating the contents of the referenced documents as useless.